# I'm a Java beginner- Convert String value to Integer using JTextField

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a simple java program that takes a string input from user through 2 boxes of Jtextfields and then convert it to integer.

These 2 integer values are then converted to decimal values by dividing them.

The decimal values are then seen by the user with a dialog box (basically a fraction to decimal converter)

When I run the program I get errors that I do not understand.

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg2CY.jpg)
[code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cubnw.jpg)

Comment: What don't you understand about that error?  The string value `""` can't be converted to an integer.  What integer value do you *expect* `""` to represent?

Comment: You need to run a GUI (search examples) and on an event calculate everything. Then int/int uses integer division throwing away the decimals, hence convert at least one side to a double: `((double)x)/y`

Comment: please text error messages - i don't see images behind a proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must throw NumberFormatException if you try to parse it to integer.

Check before parsing. or handle Exception properly.

```
    Exception Handling*

    try{
       int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
       ...
    }
```

or

```
- Integer pattern matching -

String input=...;
String pattern ="-?\\d+";
if(input.matches("-?\\d+")){ // any positive or negetive integer or not!
 ...
}
```